# DjangoRestFramework - What does "suffix" do in when creating Custom Routes?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to follow this link to create my own custom router: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#example

For the first route, there is a line which says

```
initkwargs={'suffix': 'List'}
```

and then for the second route, there is a line which says:

```
initkwargs={'suffix': 'Detail'}
```

What exactly does this line do? When I scroll up and read what is mentioned here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#custom-routers it says

```
initkwargs: A dictionary of any additional arguments that should be passed when instantiating the view. Note that the suffix argument is reserved for identifying the viewset type, used when generating the view name and breadcrumb links.
```

It doesn't look like I even need initkwargs in my custom route (I don't have any additional arguments which I need to pass to the view). What exactly is meant by "Note that the suffix argument is reserved for identifying the 'viewset type'"? I can't see what benefit this has. (Doesn't 'mapping' already show what action it is? List, Retrieve etc.?).

Answer (score 1):

The field `suffix` is used in the API view output of the REST framework. The title of the page is set to "{basename} {suffix}" for the particular route. It has no effect other than cosmetic ones. "Identifying the viewset type" is not a programmatic thing, which I think is where you got confused – it simply means identifying it in the API display pages.

It's possibly not the most useful thing but it does improve the API display slightly to see "MyCoolAPI List" etc. especially if you have multiple routes that use the same mappings. The `suffix` then allows you to easily distinguish them when viewing the API.

You are free not to set it in `initkwargs`, but if `suffix` is not set then the title of all the API pages is simply "{basename}".